# Executable java jar can't find resources path

Tags: java, jar

When i run the app in VSC it all works fine but when i generate the jar and execute it, doesnt seem to read the file as it supposed to be. I read lot of questions similar but i still cant find the solution.

Basically I have to read all the .mp3 files from the folder "/sounds/music/MainThemes", and add them to the list: "mainThemeMediaList".
The prints ( --- number --) i'm using as logging and when I run the Jar it prints me up to --- 2 --- and does not enter the while loop.
It seems that the buff read does not read the stream and thus results in null, and the list does not fill.
I am new to java so any help is appreciated.

```
    private void loadMainThemes() throws AudioLoadingException {
        try {
            System.out.println("--- 1 ---");
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/music/MainThemes");
            System.out.println(inputStream);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                System.out.println(reader);
                String line;
                System.out.println("--- 2 ---");
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("--- 3 ---");
                    if (line.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                        System.out.println("--- 4 ---");
                        Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/sounds/music/MainThemes/" + line).toString());
                        System.out.println("--- 5 ---");
                        mainThemeMediaList.add(media);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new AudioLoadingException("MainThemes resource not found.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AudioLoadingException("Failed to load MainThemes. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: *InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/music/MainThemes");* is not going to work. That, by definition of your code which follows, is a resource *folder*. What I *think* your purpose is can be fulfilled by making that something like `InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/music/MainThemes/index.txt");` and reading your real resource paths out of *that*

Comment: g00se response fixed it thanks